# Text inside of a div changes the position of it

Tags: html, css

As you can see in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BDVPP/ my big rectangle is below the position it should be in. If you delete the text inside of it, everything is fine. What does the text has to do with the position of a div? How can I fix this?

```
<div class="cont">
<div class="doubleTile">THIS TEXT MESSES UP EVERYTHING //remove this text to achieve the desired position
</div>
<div class="tile">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/BDVPP/3/

Comment: I see it, why not just use `float: left` ??

Comment: @tymeJV: This is what I am looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/BDVPP/4/ (but of course with text inside of it.

Comment: @ojek here you go http://jsfiddle.net/BDVPP/6/ using float

Comment: @PedroEstrada: What if I tell you, that I have more of them? Much more in many combinations? :)

Comment: @ojek then give me all of them and we'll make them fit

Comment: @PedroEstrada: Okay, just let's say that I don't want the float solution. It works here, but it may break something later.

Comment: @ojek if you dont want to use float, then use tables

Comment: Or you can just add `vertical-align: bottom;` as the default value for elements in the inline formatting context is baseline: http://jsfiddle.net/BDVPP/9/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/BDVPP/8/

- Use `display: block` instead of `inline-block`;
- Use `float: left` to get the elements alongside one-another, irrespective of their contents.

Answer (score 5):

The main reson its because one box has content inside it and the other one doesn't have

Just add a `&nbsp;` to the empty div and you are fine no reason to change for float.

Here is the [Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vinizinmoraes/BDVPP/10/)